# What type of torch is used during Mahabharata times?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata

There are several statements in Mahabharata that mentions the usage of torch, which provides light, mostly at night times.

Consider the following instances mentioning the usage of torch

> Dhananjaya, that mighty car-warrior, walking before them, **torch in
> hand, for showing the way** and guarding them (against wild
> animals)........Then Dhananjaya, the son of Pandu, wielding a good
> shield and **the torch he held in his hand**, warded off all those arrows
> and addressing the Gandharva again .......
>
> [[Section 172, Chaitraratha Parva, Adi Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01173.htm)
>
> Thus afflicted by him, O Bharata, the Pandava troops, at dead of
> night, broke and fled away like clouds dispersed by a tempest.
> Similarly, thy host also, mingled with the shafts of Ghatotkacha, fled
> away at dead of night, O king, in thousands, **throwing down their
> torches**.
>
> [[Section 174, Ghatotkacha-badha Parva, Drona Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07171.htm)

Do Mahabharata or any other scriptures throw light on the torch part during or before Mahabharata timings? What is the actual Sanskrit word used for torch?